# Change output of whoami to uppercase in shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to save the output of whoami to a different variable after changing it to uppercase. Please help me. I am newbie to shell scripting.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pure **`bash`**

```
x=$(whoami)
v=${x^^}
```

---

Using **`tr`**

```
v=$(whoami | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z')
```

Or

```
v=$(whoami | tr [:lower:] [:upper:])
```

---

Using **`awk`**

```
v=$(whoami | awk '{print toupper($0)}')
```

---

Using **`perl`**

```
v=$(whoami | perl -e 'print uc <>')
```